# os.path.exists returns false but not raising exception in try/except block

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to validate a list of input directories and want the script to raise errors if the directories do not exist. I don't believe if-not will work here since if these folders do not exist (with the required input files [I have another validation for this]) then the script cannot run.

```
folder1 = "d:\\temp\\exists"
folder2 = "d:\\temp\\notexists"
list = [folder1, folder2]
list #gives ['d:\\temp\\exists', 'd:\\temp\\notexists']

for l in list:
    try:
        os.path.exists(l)
        print("{0} folder exists...".format(l))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("{0} folder does not exist!".format(l))
```

`os.path.exists` correctly identifies folder2 as not existing, but does not raise an exception:

```
True
d:\temp\exists folder exists...
False
d:\temp\notexists folder exists...
```

Comment: You can reach that code without errors, so the code will not go to the exception block. The path.exists gives a boolean that tells you if a path exists, so even when it does not

Comment: Calling ``os.path.exists`` does not raise any errors if the file does not exist (it just returns ``False``). Why do you think ``FileNotFoundError`` would be raised in your code?

Comment: You could raise a generic exception like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954408/11764049)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the code to stop and raise an error:

```
for l in list: 
    if os.path.exists(l): 
        print("{0} folder exists...".format(l))
   else:
      raise FileNotFoundError("{0} folder does not exist!".format(l))
```

Comment: I want it to stop the code and raise an error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`if...else` block should do the trick

```
folder1 = "d:\\temp\\exists"
folder2 = "d:\\temp\\notexists"
list = [folder1, folder2]
list #gives ['d:\\temp\\exists', 'd:\\temp\\notexists']

for l in list:
    if os.path.exists(l)
        print("{0} folder exists...".format(l))
    else:
        print("{0} folder does not exist!".format(l))
```

Comment: if the folders are not present, the rest of the code cannot run properly. Thanks.