# Correct Python exception for not including correct combination of key-word arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, arguments

Is there a convention for raising errors if the proper combination of key-word arguments is not provided in a function call?

As an example:

```
def convert(miles=0, kilometers=0):
  if miles and not kilometers:
    return miles * 1.61
  elif kilometers and not miles:
    return kilometers / 1.61
  else:
    raise #exception
```

In this function, the one or the other parameter must receive an argument; if there are zero or two arguments, the function is invalid.

The [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) do not include an exception that is obvious for this situation. The option I have considered is `TypeError` (used in other bad function calls). Is this the standard way to handle this situation or should I use a different exception?

By the way, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256222/which-exception-should-i-raise-on-bad-illegal-argument-combinations-in-python), but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: How is that other question different from yours?

Comment: He is talking about values. I am talking about arguments being there or not, zero representing no argument.

Comment: @bcdan You're looking for **values of the arguments** rather than the arguments themselves. If the issue is absence of a positional argument (if user forgets to specify) the function would automatically raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: You can always derive your own exception class from `Exception` and `raise` an instance of it.

Comment: @bcdan: You are talking about values.  Zero is a value.  You can't distinguish between the user passing in zero explicitly and not passing in a value at all.

Answer (score 2):

> **ValueError**
>   Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError

**One more thing...**

If a function only has keyword arguments, users might confuse it as something they can call without specifying anything. Here you have no way of knowing which conversion they have in mind. You **must have at least 2 positional arguments** to calculate the values, or you can make two separate functions with one argument each.

I would recommend this:

```
def miles2km(miles=1):
    return miles * 1.60934

def km2miles(km=1):
    return 1.0/miles2km(1.0/km) if km else 0
```

The reason why I prefer this is because only one function needs to be maintained, since the conversion factor is only present in one of them.

Comment: `km2miles` also needs to handle an argument of 0 correctly.

Comment: @chepner I hate that bug! Thank you for noticing - will edit.