# What is the standard exception for a missing value in python?

Tags: python, exception

Which standard python exception, if any, should be used in the case where a value is missing for the proper execution of a function ? `TypeError` and `ValueError` seemed good candidates to me but according to the documentation (my italics) :

> Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a `list` when an `int` is expected) should result in a `TypeError`, but passing arguments with the wrong value (e.g. a number outside expected boundaries) should result in a `ValueError`.
>
> **ValueError** : Raised when an operation or function receives *an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value*, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Neither of these descriptions seem to me to quite capture the idea of a missing value. But none of the other exceptions in the standard seem to come even close either.

Here's an example. Objects of type `myclass` can be instantiated in two different ways, each of which requires a specific parameter. If neither of them is provided, the init fails.

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,firstparam=None,secondparam=None):
        if firstparam:
             self.firstinit()
        elif secondparam:
             self.secondinit()
        else:
           #What to put here ?
           raise Exception("Missing value for myclass")

if __name__=="__main__":
    #oops, forgot to specify a parameter here !
    myobj=myclass()
```

Of course, I know I can always implement my own `MissingValueError` exceptions subclasses when writing a library. I am asking this question in order not to duplicate something that might already exist in the standard.

Comment: I don't think the Python standard exceptions cover this situation specifically, as it's a very scenario-specific situation. If I were you, I'd create my own exception to be thrown on construction of the object, or stick with the generic `Exception` class.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb Is it really such a scenario specific situation ? The example I give is very specific of course, but the concept of a missing value seems to be appropriate in a variety of situations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256222/which-exception-should-i-raise-on-bad-illegal-argument-combinations-in-python

Comment: @DanD. I would argue that this is a misuse of valueerror. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError clearly states that it's for values with "the right type". You can't check the type of a missing value.

Comment: To make it clear, my distinction between the two, is that when you provide multiple default parameters, and you're checking that at least one is non-Falsy, or at least, not the default, your exception isn't that _you've provided the wrong type_, but that you _weren't given at least one of the sufficient types_, which I'd argue is a very subtle, but valid, difference between the two that makes this a "specific scenario".

Comment: But after thinking about it, maybe this is roughly a matter of perspective. I'd still argue that this should be a custom exception if we're concerned about throwing the "right one", but if you _must_ bubble a specific Python exception, I'd side with @lenik that the most appropriate would be `TypeError`, so long as you don't expect a falsy value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper exception would be `TypeError`:

```
>>> def a(b,c) : print b,c
... 
>>> a(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

And as a side note, I'd recommend NOT to provide the default values to the required arguments, so the user of your class will clearly understand (s)he has to provide some.

Comment: It's a good solution if both arguments are required, but in my example, I only really need one or the other.

Comment: @Typhon and when I call `MyClass(42)` -- is `42` the first param or the second? =)

Comment: it's not one of the defined keyword parameters that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your own custom validation exception.

Something like this:

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, firstparam=None, secondparam=None):
        if firstparam:
            self.firstinit()
        elif secondparam:
            self.secondinit()
        else:
            # What to put here ?
            raise ValidationError("Either firstparam or secondparam should be passed")

    def firstinit(self):
        pass

    def secondinit(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #oops, forgot to specify a parameter here !
    try:
        myobj=MyClass()
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err)
```

Output:

```
Either firstparam or secondparam should be passed
```

Comment: I know I can create a custom exception, the purpose of this question was to ask whether there was already an exception in the standard library for this type of problem.